# configurable decimal input format in a DataGridView column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, input, decimal

I have an app that allows user to input decimal values, like 00.000, 00.00, 0000.0 and so on.

The problem is that different users require different formats, and I'd like to offer a feature to configure this input format to the end users (like an input template or mask).

What do you think is the best approach to get this accomplished?

Comment: do you mean different formats as in decimal character (0,123 or 0.123) or delimiters (1000 or 1 000) and so on? Did you check the arguments that you can pass to [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `IFormatProvider` and use `the Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` Method to define how the decimals are going to be parsed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t7xswkc6.aspx fpr Method description

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/custstrformat.aspx for a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

/*
why not make your own method that checks the format length and do something like this as a starting point.

lets say the user typed in the following //replace the following with what ever you are checking against a textbox input.
//This is something that I have quickly written up to test the text that I am passing. 
*/

```
   tmpStringTest+= FormatNumberWithCommas(100.ToString()) + " ";
   tmpStringTest += FormatNumberWithCommas(1000.ToString());
   tmpStringTest += FormatNumberWithCommas(10000.ToString());
   tmpStringTest += FormatNumberWithCommas(100000.ToString());
   tmpStringTest += FormatNumberWithCommas(1000000.ToString());

   public static string FormatNumberWithCommas(string inputString)
   {
       string tempString;
       tempString = string.Format("{0:##,###,###}", Convert.ToInt32(inputString));
       return tempString;
   }
```